# linear gradient effecting an elements z-index

Tags: css, html

Can anyone explain to me why I can't get the search elements come to the front on this page: http://blog.uniplaces.com/author/sebastiaan/ (aka infront of the linear background). I was able to do it with the search button via this:

```
.some_element { z-index: 1; }
```

But for the other elements it does not work. It seems as though the linear gradient is causing this. Because if I add a z-index -1 to:

```
.error-content:after { z-index: -1; }
```

The entire gradient disappears but the form elements function as planned.

```
.error-content.not-found {
    background: url(http://www.uniplaces.com/dist/img/static/not-found.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
}
.error-content:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #363636 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 85%, #363636 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #363636 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 85%, #363636 100%);
}
```

Comment: make z-index: 9999 (max) and try lowering the backgrounds index

Comment: do i have to apply it on a per element basis or to the entire div that contains the elements that should be in the foreground?

Comment: entire grid with the search area should do the trick

Comment: not working, if I lower the z-index (lower than 0) of the background with the gradient the gradient disappears. and if i increase the other elements z-indexes nothing happens. in chrome dev tools see for yourself.

Comment: how you are setting background image can you show some code?

Comment: attached to question, but its probably easier to follow the link

Comment: `.view-all { position: relative; z-index: 1; }`

Comment: @SexyTurnip how could i have missed that (facepalm)